# Why is .setValue() in for-loop skipping columns?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sirishortcuts

I have this web app in Appscript that receives info from a POST request from Siri Shortcuts.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  
  //Get active spreadsheet and input database tab name.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test02');
  
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
    //Retrieve data received and make a string.
    var data = JSON.stringify(e);
  
    //1st print. Print string on new row.
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(data);
  
    //Eliminate all special characters coming from Siri Shortcuts POST request.
    data = data.replace(new RegExp(["\\\\"], 'g'), "");
    data = data.replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), "");
    data = data.replace(new RegExp("{", 'g'), "");
    data = data.replace(new RegExp("}", 'g'), "");
    data = data.replace(new RegExp(":", 'g'), "");
  
    //Split all info on the left side of the first parameter and on the right side of the second.
    data = data.split('Log')[1];
    data = data.split("name")[0];

    //2nd print. Print clean string on a new row.    
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(data);  
     
    //3rd print. Print all array element on row. End goal is to have them start from column A and keep adding 1 column every loop.
    //Split string into array.
    var dataArray = data.split(",");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      //3rd print, first part. This tests the real data.
      sheet.getRange(lastRow,1+[i]).setValue(dataArray[i]);
      //3rd print, second part. This tests the index number to try and find why row are being skipped.
      sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1+[i]).setValue([i]);
    }
  
    //Use Mail app to send mail after completion.  
    MailApp.sendEmail("abc123@gmail.com","InningLogger - Test", data); 
    
    return;
  
}
```

Attached is the result I am getting in the spreadsheet. [image: Spreadsheet Result]

I have two problems with rows 3 and 7:

1. Why is the data not starting from column A?
2. Why is row 7 skipping a ton
   of columns (I hid them for the screenshot) to print the last 3
   values?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you intend `1+[i]` to mean? Because `i` is a number in your code, say 3, `1+[i]` will be the string "13", not a number.

Comment: Ahh! How could I fix that? My intention was to use [i] as an index to set the column number that determines the .setValue() range.

Comment: Well if `i` is the number 3 then `1 + i` is the number 4.  The `[ ]` create an array, which is then converted back to a string when `1+[i]` is evaluated.

Comment: Yes! It is working now, thanks a lot! Just changed 1+[i] for [i+1]. Would you like to answer the question or should I copy your first comment to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy mentioned, the problem lied within the 1+[i] in the for loop. "Because i is a number in your code, say 3, 1+[i] will be the string "13", not a number. Changing this to [i+1] solved the problem completely.